# ESlint error JS : Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am calling multiple function (with promise) will be returned .. code is working perfectly fine for me but I need to ESlint error free code.. at the moment I get the below error for this..

Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body  arrow-body-style

could you please advise on this...

```
this.test1 = function() {
return this.test2().then((val1) => {
    return this.test3().then((val2) => {
        return this.test4().then((values) => {
            const nameValues = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < values; i += 1) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < val1; j += 1) {
                      //some code
                    }
                } else if (i === 1) {
                    for (let k = 0; k < val2; k += 1) {
                        //some code
                    }
                }
            }
            return //some value;
        });
    });
});
```

};

Comment: I'm not getting any EsLint errors, apart from `nameValues` assigned but never used.

Comment: Does it not also give some indication as to which line it's referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linter rule expects you to remove the `{}` from your arrow function because your function body has only a return statement, which ordinarily is expressed without `{}` or the `return` keyword (shown below).

```
this.test2().then((val1) =>
this.test3().then((val2) =>
this.test4().then((values) => {  const nameValues = []; /* ... */ }
```

Comment: yes now my lint errors are gone but I had other issues like my script was failing with "then' of undefined"..

Comment: if you add `.then()` after a function call, then you should make sure that that function returns a promise. e.g. here the `this.test3()` if it returns `[1,2,3]` then you could not call `then` on it, but with `return Promise.resolve([1,2,3]) that's ok

Answer (score 0):

Try this eslint configuration

```
"arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"]
```